# How do I express an extended subtype of a generic object in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I want to set an attribute on an object, but keep the rest of the object intact, e.g.

```py
from typing import cast, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class HasFoo(Generic[T]):
    foo: str


def set_foo_on_obj(obj: T) -> HasFoo[T]:
    setattr(obj, 'foo', 'some_value')
    return cast(HasFoo[T], obj)


def func(a: int) -> int:
    return a


func_with_foo = set_foo_on_obj(func)
```

Here I'm trying to add the attribute `foo`, and tell the type checker "it's the same object as before, but has a `foo` attribute now.

But the above example simple erases other properties of the callable.

Comment: In TypeScript this is possible with [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). In python, however, such a construct does not yet exist. Read more in the following issues in the typing repo: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/18 https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @paweł-rubin, there is no elegant/direct way that generalizes over any given type so long as intersection types are missing from the type system.

You can write workarounds with different degrees of complexity for specific use cases though using structural subtyping with what is already offered by [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). If it is a simple callable you want to "enhance" with your added protocol, you can do something like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar, cast


T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


class HasFoo(Protocol):
    foo: str


class CallableWithFoo(HasFoo, Generic[P, T]):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...


def set_foo_on_func(function: Callable[P, T]) -> CallableWithFoo[P, T]:
    function.foo = "some_value"
    return cast(CallableWithFoo[P, T], function)


def func(a: int) -> int:
    return a


func_with_foo = set_foo_on_func(func)

reveal_type(func_with_foo)      # CallableWithFoo[[a: builtins.int], builtins.int]
reveal_type(func_with_foo(1))   # builtins.int
reveal_type(func_with_foo.foo)  # builtins.str
```

The use of [`typing.ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) in our generic class allows retaining the callable signature after decoration.

Obviously, other types (not `Callable` subtypes) will require other protocol inheritance. But this is probably as good as it gets without proper intersection types.

There is also no way around `typing.cast` IMO because dynamic attribute assignment is ignored by static type checkers for obvious reasons.

**EDIT**: Changed the `setattr(function, "foo", "some_value")` to regular attribute assignment. Thanks @SUTerliakov for pointing it out.

Comment: @SUTerliakov You're right, I edited it.

Comment: Thanks. One question about the `setattr` though. Why did you specifically opt for using the static attribute access, since technically that attribute doesn't exist on the type, before the cast?

Comment: @komodovaran_ No, technically `cast` has nothing to do with it. That is just for the benefit of static type checkers. We know the attribute name in advance, so there is no need to use `setattr`. Regular attribute assignment is clearer and thus less error prone. Writing `function.foo = "some_value"` calls the underlying `__setattr__` method of `function`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__